# Values entered in a meta box aren't saved

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I developed a custom metabox plugin and linked it to contact us page in order to save to DB the phone number, email and working hours as user input.

The thing values I entered are not save into DB.

Kindly look into this matter and help me to find a solution.

**metabox.php** - plugin

```
<?php

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wpl_owt_register_metabox_cpt');
function wpl_owt_register_metabox_cpt()
{
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-contact.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'owt-cpt-id', // $id
                'Contact Details', // $title
                'wpl_owt_book_function', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}


   /**********Callback function for metabox at custom post type book******************/

 function wpl_owt_book_function( $post ) {
    //echo "<p>Custom metabox for custom post type</p>";

    define("_FILE_", "_FILE_");

    wp_nonce_field( basename(_FILE_), "wp_owt_cpt_nonce");

    echo "<label for='txtPhoneNum'>Phone</label><br>";
    $phone_num = get_post_meta($post->ID, "telNo" , true);
    echo "<input type ='tel' name = 'txtPhoneNum' value = '" . $phone_num . "'' placeholder = 'Phone Number' /><br><br>";

    echo "<label for='txtEmail'>Email</label><br>";
    $email = get_post_meta($post->ID, "email" , true);
    echo "<input type ='email' name = 'txtEmail' value = '" . $email . "'' placeholder = 'Email Address' /><br><br>";

    echo "<label for='txtHours'>Hours of Operation</label><br>";
    $hours = get_post_meta($post->ID, "hourofOps" , true);
    echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtHours' value = '" . $hours . "'' placeholder = 'Working Hours' /><br><br>";
}

add_action("save_post" , "wpl_owt_save_metabox_data" , 10 , 2);

function wpl_owt_save_metabox_data($post_id, $post){

    //verify nonce
    if(!isset($_POST['wp_owt_cpt_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_owt_cpt_nonce'], basename(_FILE_))){
        return $post_id;
    }

    //verify slug value
    $post_slug = "book";
    if($post_slug != $post->post_type){
        return;
    }

    //save value to db filed
    $pub_tel = '';
    if(isset($_POST['txtPhoneNum'])){
        $pub_tel = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtPhoneNum']);
    }

    else{
        $pub_tel = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "telNo", $pub_tel);


    $pub_email = '';

    if(isset($_POST['txtEmail'])){
        $pub_email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtEmail']);
    }

    else{
        $pub_email = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "email", $pub_email);


    $pub_hours = '';

    if(isset($_POST['txtHours'])){
        $pub_hours = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtHours']);
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, "hourofOps", $pub_hours);
}

?>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `if($post_slug != $post->post_type){}` from save function or change `$post_slug = "book";` to `$post_slug = "page";`. because it check `$post` slug is `book` or not. currently post type is `page` for contact us page. and you have set as `book`

```
add_action("save_post" , "wpl_owt_save_metabox_data" , 10 , 2);

function wpl_owt_save_metabox_data($post_id, $post){

    //verify nonce
    if(!isset($_POST['wp_owt_cpt_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_owt_cpt_nonce'], basename(_FILE_))){
        return $post_id;
    }

    //save value to db filed
    $pub_tel = '';
    if(isset($_POST['txtPhoneNum'])){
        $pub_tel = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtPhoneNum']);
    }
    else{
        $pub_tel = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "telNo", $pub_tel);


    $pub_email = '';

    if(isset($_POST['txtEmail'])){
        $pub_email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtEmail']);
    }
    else{
        $pub_email = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "email", $pub_email);


    $pub_hours = '';

    if(isset($_POST['txtHours'])){
        $pub_hours = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtHours']);
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, "hourofOps", $pub_hours);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It wordked.

Comment: You are welcome!